# Correct order of methods to load OpenSSL?

Tags: c, openssl

There are several initialization methods in OpenSSL

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
SSL_load_error_strings();     /* Bring in and register error messages */
SSL_library_init();
```

Is there a specific order in which they have to be called, if I am using TLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little vague, yet:

The order of `SSL_load_error_strings()` and `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()` doesn't technically matter.

If you are using OpenSSL 1.1.0 or newer, you do not need to call `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()` at all. [The function has been deprecated and superseded by `OPENSSL_init_crypto()`.](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms.html)

[This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSL/Initialization) suggests initialization be performed in this order:

```
[first, set up threading callbacks if your program is multithreaded]
SSL_load_error_strings ();
SSL_library_init ();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms ();
OPENSSL_config (NULL);
```

You may also want to check out what it says in the [OpenSSL Wiki on initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization)

Comment: Since I'm using 1.1.0, does that mean the proper order for me is 1) `SSL_load_error_strings()`, 2) `OPENSSL_init_ssl()`, 3) `OPENSSL_init_crypto()` Additionally, are there recommended parameters to pass into `OPENSSL_init_ssl()` and `OPENSSL_init_crypto()` and if so, where can I find the documentation on them? Reading the following documents: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/OPENSSL_init_crypto.html and https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/OPENSSL_init_ssl.html did not give me information/examples on what values to pass in for parameters.

Comment: Yes, but do note in 1.1.0 and later, this is only necessary if you are doing something non-standard: `As of version 1.1.0 OpenSSL will automatically allocate all resources that it needs so no explicit initialisation is required. Similarly it will also automatically deinitialise as required.`

Comment: For your purposes, OpenSSL 1.1.x will allocate all resources automatically. It's only in cases where you are doing something special that you would need to call these functions directly. (and in those cases, they may not be in this order.)

Comment: Great, so from my understanding, that means no initialization code/functional calls are necessary.

Comment: I use openssl v1.1.1 , it is not necessary to call `SSL_load_error_strings()` , you can directly call `OPENSSL_init_ssl(opts, NULL)` where `opts` is a flag set including `OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_SSL_STRINGS` and `OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CRYPTO_STRINGS`